# Is there a way to incorporate the OpenSCAD compiler in java or any other programming language?

Tags: java, c++, openscad

I am currently using OpenScad to create a template code (where I insert values to the input variables) in order to generate 3D models.

The reason I am doing this is part of a larger project where I want to iteratively generate 3D models based on an evolutionary algorithm applied to the input variables where user preference will dictate the direction of evolution. 
(user choose a model from a selection of models and new models will be generated from the chosen model, rinse and repeat)

I want to be able to design a user interface for this. Is it possible for me to use the OpenScad compiler (and renderer if possible) in a programming language like Java (where I can design a UI for my program)?

P.S. I am a beginner so go easy on me

Answer (score 1):

OpenSCAD is written in C++, so while integration with Java is possible, it's not something I'd recommend as it's probably a fair bit of work.

We're discussing adding a user-definable GUI like this to OpenSCAD. It's still being discussed with some early results published. All this is kind of in the expert domain until it's done, but see here for ideas/inspiration/info:

- https://github.com/openscad/openscad/tree/model-meta-data3
- https://github.com/openscad/openscad/wiki/Project%3A-Form-based-script-parameterization
- https://github.com/openscad/openscad/issues/722
- https://www.flickr.com/photos/96851846@N05/16000210899/
- http://files.openscad.org/video/screencast-parameter-window.webm
- http://files.openscad.org/video/screencast-library-window.webm

For an easier starting point for beginners, perhaps OpenJSCAD is good? That would give you a web app, which you could change to add your own GUI controls: http://openjscad.org/

See here for an example of someone who wrote their own UI on top of OpenJSCAD: http://custom.3dprintler.com/

All of these solutions still require a bit of tinkering - nothing is plug & play : /

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I can use OpenJSCAD to create my own interface? Or should I just take apart the source code from the website in order to do that? Do you think that is the right direction for me to go?

Comment: OpenJSCAD is not a turn-key solution for this, but they do have support for writing your own customization UIs - look at their examples named "Interactive Params: *". If you want to hide the OpenJSCAD UI and provide your own look and feel, you could fork the project and rewrite the code as you wish.

Comment: Is it currenly possible to interface it with C++? Some sort of API to pass the openscad code and get back a list of vetex/faces? So you can recreate such model in your game/app?

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use the OpenSCAD CLI in your program, something like:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("input.scad", "UTF-8");
writer.println("cube();");
writer.close();

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("openscad -o output.stl input.scad");
```

and then you can just use another library to display the STL file.

You can read more about the OpenSCAD CLI here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment

Answer (score 0):

BowlerStudio from Commonwealth Robotics is a full robot design, development, programming, testing stack, which includes 3D CAD:

https://github.com/CommonWealthRobotics/BowlerStudio

programmed in Java and using an extension of Java code for 3D modeling, it should be familiar and workable to folks who know that programming language.